# Why is my batch script giving following error " ' ' is not recognized"?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I was creating this **batch script to extract password of any Wi-Fi previously connected to my device.** This script **asks user to input the SSID** and then extracts the password using `netsh wlan show profile=%Wi-Fi name% key=clear`, but while executing so, I encountered this error multiple times:
`' ' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I tried replacing the variable `cmnd` with the actual code i.e `netsh wlan....` in the `FOR \f` statement but then no significant output was visible.

Any suggestions as to what am doing wrong?

*My Code:*

```
@echo Welcome to this Password Extractor tool.
set /p WiFi_Name=Enter the SSID.
set cmnd=netsh wlan show profile name=%WiFi_Name% key=clear
for /f "tokens=1-2,17" %%i in ('%cmnd%') do ^ 
if "%%i %%j"=="Key Content" set PASS=%%k
echo%PASS%
Pause
```

*The Command Prompt Window shows following error:*

```
Welcome to this Password Extractor tool.

C:\Program Files\PowerToys>set /p WiFi_Name=Enter the SSID.
Enter the SSID.Skti

C:\Program Files\PowerToys>set cmnd=netsh wlan show profile name=Skti key=clear

C:\Program Files\PowerToys>for /F "tokens=1-2,17" %i in ('netsh wlan show profile name Skti key clear') do

C:\Program Files\PowerToys>
' ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files\PowerToys>
' ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files\PowerToys>
' ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files\PowerToys>
' ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files\PowerToys>
' ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files\PowerToys>
' ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files\PowerToys>
' ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files\PowerToys>
' ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files\PowerToys>
' ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files\PowerToys>
' ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files\PowerToys>
' ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files\PowerToys>
' ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files\PowerToys>
' ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files\PowerToys>
' ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files\PowerToys>
' ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files\PowerToys>
' ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files\PowerToys>
' ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files\PowerToys>
' ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files\PowerToys>
' ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files\PowerToys>
' ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files\PowerToys>
' ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files\PowerToys>
' ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files\PowerToys>
' ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files\PowerToys>
' ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files\PowerToys>if "%i %j" == "Key Content" set PASS=%k

C:\Program Files\PowerToys>echo
ECHO is on.
```

Comment: My guess: You have one or many  _"space"_ after the `^` of  `do ^` of the `for` command. Remove it/them. And use `set "PASS=%%k"`. Beware of blank/space in batch, they're an agonizing pain, they're meaningful where you expecting them the less.

Comment: Why do you try to use line continuation (`^`) rather than a parenthesised block?

Comment: I just thought I'd mention that your `set /p` prompt is requesting the end user to type in the SSID. Then your code is using the SSID as the Profile Name, when it is not the same thing. Whilst I accept that the SSID and Profile Names are often the same, by default, in large ISP customer routers etc. they are configurable settings. If you want them to provide the name of the profile, you should ask them to type the name of the profile. Or you could provide a numbered list of the profiles, present them to the end user, and prompt them to select one of those, using the choice.exe command.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use something a little more robust:

```sh
For /F "Tokens=3,*" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\netsh.exe WLAN Show Profiles Name^="%WiFi_Name%" Key^="Clear" 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /RC:"^  *Key Content  *: *[^ ][^ ]*.*$"') Do Set "PASS=%%H"
```

…and if you wanted to split that long line for readability then:

```sh
For /F "Tokens=3,*" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\netsh.exe WLAN Show Profiles
 Name^="%WiFi_Name%" Key^="Clear" 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe
 /RC:"^  *Key Content  *: *[^ ][^ ]*.*$"') Do Set "PASS=%%H"
```

*Please be aware that the netsh.exe output is returned in the configured sytem language, so if you intend to distribute this, please be awre that any password will not always be preceded by the English case sensitive string `Key Content`*

Comment: I tried running your script, but it says ```The system cannot find the file WLAN.```

Comment: @RishabhTiwari, if you ran **my** script you shouldn't have gotten such a message. If you made any changes whatsoever to the layout or content of exactly what I've posted above, then I cannot support you with that. Please update your question with exactly the content of your batch file, without `echo`ing turned `on` and run it from a Command Prompt window, posting the output it returns too. BTW, the code, unlike most of mine, has been tested, because I had a Windows PC available on that day to test it on!

Answer (score 0):

IT MAY SOLVE YOUR PROBLEM.

```
@ECHO OFF
echo Welcome to this Password Extractor tool.
set /p WiFi_Name=Enter the SSID: 
netsh wlan show profile name=%WiFi_Name% key=clear>"%tmp%\wifi.log"
findstr /n "Key Content" "%tmp%\wifi.log">"%tmp%\wifi1.log"
del /q /f "%tmp%\wifi.log"
set /p pass=<%tmp%\wifi1.log
for /f "tokens=3 delims=:" %%a in ("%pass%") do (
  SET PASS=%%a
  )
SET PASS=%PASS%B
del /q /f "%tmp%\wifi1.log"
set PASS=%PASS:~1,-1%
ECHO PASSWORD: %PASS%
pause
```

IT CREATE SOME REQUIRED FILES INTO TEMP FOLDER AND REMOVES AFTER THE OPERATION  COMPLETE